# SQL Query to get desired result from three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I use 5 table for my photo gallery to store different information

Photos, PhotoDetails, PhotoMappings, PhotoAlbum, PhotoAlbumCategory.

This is a multilingual website & i want to upload photo for album once & share them with any language version of website.

Steps involved.

1. I add photo to Photos TABLE
2. Second i map photo to particular album along with (LanguageID, AlbumID, AlbumCategoryID) in PhotoMapping table
3. Third  i need to add details related to particular photo like Title, Description, date ...

In order to add details i want to show user list of photos under particular album along with additional information like YES/NO based on if details of this photo are in Photodetails table.

```
PhotoDetails
    [PhotoDetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PhotoTitle] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [PhotoDesc] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhotoDate] [date] NULL,
    [PhotoVisible] [bit] NULL,
    [PhotoID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AlbumID] [int] NULL,
    [LanguageID] [int] NULL,
    [PhotoDetailsCreatedOn] [date] NULL

PhotoMappings
    [MappingID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LanguageID] [int] NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NULL,
    [AlbumID] [int] NULL,
    [PhotoID] [int] NULL,

Photos
    [PhotoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PhotoTN] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PhotoLarge] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PhotoGUID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PhotoCreatedOn] [date] NULL,


SELECT d.PhotoTitle,d.AlbumID,p.PhotoTN AS TN,  p.PhotoID AS PID,p.PhotoLarge AS PL,
case when d.PhotoId is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end AS [Details]
FROM Photos p  JOIN  PhotoDetails d
ON  p.PhotoId = d.PhotoId JOIN PhotoMappings m
ON  p.PhotoId = m.PhotoId WHERE d.AlbumID  = 14 and m.LanguageID = 1
```

I need to write a query which will show me all the records in PhotoMapping table along with those rows which are not present in the PhotoDetails Table.

I am using above query it gets me the desired result but doesn't show me the column which is not present in PhotoDetails Table

I want OUTPUT to be like as show below suppose  i want details regarding album where AlbumID=14 & Language =1 ( I get only first 6 rows from my query)

```
PhotoTitle      AlbumID TN      PID PL  Details         
Title of Photo1 14      1Icon.JPG   16  1.JPG   YES
Title of Photo2 14      2Icon.JPG   21  2.JPG   YES
Title of Photo3 14      3Icon.JPG   20  3.JPG   YES
Title of Photo4 14      4Icon.JPG   22  4.JPG   YES
Title of Photo5 14      5Icon.JPG   18  5.JPG   YES
Title of Photo6 14      6Icon.JPG   17  6.JPG   YES
Title of Photo7 14      7Icon.JPG   23  7.JPG   NO
Title of Photo8 14      8Icon.JPG   24  8.JPG   NO
```

I would appreciate help in this regarding i did change `JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` & `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` but out put remain same

Sample Data

**Mapping Table**

```
MappingID   LanguageID  CategoryID  AlbumID PhotoID
1   1   7   14  16
2   1   7   14  21
3   1   7   14  20
4   1   7   14  22
5   1   7   14  19
6   1   7   14  18
7   1   7   14  17
8   1   7   14  23
```

Sample Data from PhotoDetails table

```
PhotoDetailsID  PhotoTitle  PhotoDate   PhotoVisible    PhotoID AlbumID LanguageID  PhotoDetailsCreatedOn
20  Title of Photo1     2012-07-02  1   16  14  1   2012-02-07
21  Title of Photo2     2012-07-02  1   17  14  1   2012-02-07
22  Title of Photo3     2012-07-02  1   18  14  1   2012-02-07
24  Title of Photo4     2012-07-02  1   20  14  1   2012-02-07
25  Title of Photo5     2012-07-02  1   21  14  1   2012-02-07
26  Title of Photo6     2012-07-02  1   22  14  1   2012-02-07
23  Title of Photo7     2012-07-02  1   19  10  1   2012-02-07
27  Title of Photo8     2012-07-02  1   23  13  1   2012-02-07
34  Something       2012-07-02  1   14  13  1   2012-02-07
35  Something       2012-03-20  1   37  17  1   2012-03-07
36  Something       2012-03-13  1   38  10  1   2012-03-07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need to change two things: filter on AlbumID should come from PhotoMappings, not PhotoDetail, and you need left join on PhotoDetails.

```
SELECT d.PhotoTitle,
       m.AlbumID,
       p.PhotoTN AS TN,
       p.PhotoID AS PID,
       p.PhotoLarge AS PL,
       case when d.PhotoId is null 
            then 'NO' 
            else 'YES' 
        end AS [Details]
  FROM Photos p
 INNER JOIN PhotoMappings m
    ON p.PhotoId = m.PhotoId
  LEFT JOIN  PhotoDetails d
    ON p.PhotoId = d.PhotoId
 WHERE m.AlbumID = 14
   and m.LanguageID = 1
```

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Please check my amended query.

Comment: It shows me 8 rows with one rows from AlbumID 10 & other from 13 & with `YES` in all fields of Details. While it should show output exactly the way i had show in part of actual question.

Comment: I am freaked-out with this query data seems to be correct i must be doing something wrong somewhere...

Comment: I don't see how it could be - there is a filter on AlbumID limiting the results to Album 14. Could you please post sample data for these three tables?

Comment: I agree with you despite filter it gets the two records of different album id. I have added the sample data for Mapping & Photodetails table

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker There are two problems: d.AlbumID in select list should read `m.AlbumID` and there is possible error in data. Photos 19 and 23 are marked as if they belong to Album 14 in mappings but details say they belong to albums 10 and 13. If this is intended, a join between Mappings and Details should be expanded to contain `and m.AlbumID = d.AlbumID`. See [this Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c575/9).

Comment: Your Fiddle Query solved the issue I am getting the correct data now. Thanks i appreciate your help. It would be great if you can add the Fiddle link to your actual answer so that i can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

left outer JOIN before PhotoMappings  should be working:

```
SELECT d.PhotoTitle,d.AlbumID,p.PhotoTN AS TN,  p.PhotoID AS PID,
p.PhotoLarge AS PL,
case when d.PhotoId is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end AS [Details]
FROM Photos p  JOIN  PhotoDetails d
ON  p.PhotoId = d.PhotoId 
left outer JOIN PhotoMappings m
ON  p.PhotoId = m.PhotoId 
WHERE d.AlbumID  = 14 and m.LanguageID = 1
```

Comment: I tried similar query before but result remains same. I tried your query also it just showed me the first 6 rows `desired output` as i had show in part of actual question